# Failed to get my expected output using left outer join

Tags: mysql

This is my sample table:

model1

```
        +-----+--------+
        | nos | nameNo |
        +-----+--------+
        | 1   | 1345   |
        | 2   | 1345   |
        | 3   | 3306   |
        +-----+--------+
```

model2

```
        +-----+--------+
        | nos | nameNo |
        +-----+--------+
        | 1   | 3701   |
        | 2   | 1345   |
        | 4   | 2876   |
        | 5   | 1343   |
        | 6   | 3572   |
        | 7   | 1793   |
        | 33  | 2041   |
        | 34  | 1509   |
        | 35  | 1577   |
        | 36  | 1869   |
        | 37  | 1578   |
        | 38  | 2876   |
        | 39  | 1345   |
        +-----+--------+
```

This is my sql query:

```
SELECT model1.nos, model1.nameNo, model2.nos, model2.nameNo  
FROM sample.model1 left outer join sample.model2 on model1.nameNo = model2.nameNo 
group by model1.nos;
```

My output:

```
        +-----+--------++-----+--------+
        | nos | nameNo | nos  | nameNo |
        +-----+--------+------+--------+
        | 1   | 1345   | 2    | 1345   |
        | 2   | 1345   | 2    | 1345   |
        | 3   | 3306   | null | null   |
        +-----+--------+------+--------+
```

My expected output should be these but I confused to my code query, please help, thanks in advance:

```
        +-----+--------++-----+--------+
        | nos | nameNo | nos  | nameNo |
        +-----+--------+------+--------+
        | 1   | 1345   | 2    | 1345   |
        | 2   | 1345   | 39   | 1345   |
        | 3   | 3306   | null | null   |
        +-----+--------+------+--------+
```

Comment: what happens if you omit `group by model1.nos`

Comment: the output will be "2,39,2,39,null" but output of nos should be "2,39,null".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Join makes a cartesian output from rows which match on a condition. You have two rows from table 1 which match two rows from table 2 on `model1.nameNo = model2.nameNo` then the output has (2x2=4) rows plus the row from table1 which has no matching from table2.

But the way you corresponded rows in your expected result are not based on a specific relation and it would be a hard task to create the result.

it seems you just want a union of the columns of the rows from both tables which have the same `nameNo`, maybe the following code help you to solve it.

```
    SELECT distinct nos, nameNo, null, null from table1
    Union
    SELECT distinct null, null, nos, nameNo from table2 
    where exists (select nameNo from table1 where table1.nameNo = table2.nameNo)
```

Comment: Error: sub query returns more than 1 row

Comment: I modified my answer, in fact you should find a relation between matching columns for each row, there is not such a relation and maybe you can't do that by join. for example why 1,1345 matches 2,1345 while 2,1345 matches 39, 1345? there is no relation between 1 and 2 and 2 and 39

Answer (score 0):

use distinct instead of group by :

```
SELECT distinct model1.nos, model1.nameNo, model2.nos, model2.nameNo  
FROM sample.model1 
left outer join sample.model2 
on model1.nameNo = model2.nameNo
```

Since MySQL extends the use of GROUP BY so that the select list can refer to nonaggregated columns not named in the GROUP BY clause. Says in [MySQL Handling of GROUP BY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-handling.html):

> However, this is useful primarily when all values in each nonaggregated column not named in the GROUP BY are the same for each group. The server is free to choose any value from each group, so unless they are the same, the values chosen are indeterminate. Furthermore, the selection of values from each group cannot be influenced by adding an ORDER BY clause.

That's why you failed to get the result expected with your query.

Comment: I tried your code but the output is "2,39,2,39,null" and output of nos should be "2,39,null" The output is correct but it still duplicate.

Comment: If the columns not named in the group by clause, and the columns' value are not the same for each group, you should use aggregation function such as `max` or `min`.

Comment: but how? how can I show my output using that MIN and MAX, I dont know how to start it. my understanding in min and max will get the minimum and maximim value of the data.

Comment: Your expected result really make no sense. Why model1.nos(1) match model2.nos(2) and model1.nos(2) match model2.nos(39)? Can you explain your logic?

Comment: because my project is to campare two tables which is my model1 and model2, my client wanted to get the unique and common value from model1 to model2 so that I wanted to check if my specific output is correct. If you mind my question I can give you my real datas.

Comment: What's the meaning of `common value`? Append a where clause after my query, such as `where model1.nos = model2.nos`. That's a choice.

Comment: common value is model1 contains in model2 unique value is model1 not contains in model2, i tried where dinstinct in model2.nows but it is not working

Comment: In my opinion, there's only (2,1345) contains in model2, isn't it?

Comment: yup!, 2,1345 and 39, 1345